# Regex to match a word followed by another word with a certain suffix

Tags: regex, grep

I need a grep regex which I want to run over a text file. The grep command should output each line of the text file which contains a word (let that word be `foo`) followed by a space and another word which ends with a certain suffix (let that suffix be `ing`).

So the regex should match sequences such as: `foo going`, `foo walking`, `foo running`

Please not that the `ing` should be in the next word after `foo`. So the regex should *not* match: `foo asfd asdfing`.

I tried

```
grep -i "foo .*ing"
```

but this matches not only on the immediate next word, it also matches if `ing` is in the second word after the `foo`.

Comment: I tried: grep -i "foo .*ing"
but this matches not only on the immediate next word. it also matches, if *ing* is in the 2nd word after the *foo*.

Comment: Add a lazy quantifier `foo .*?ing` or `foo\s+\S*ing`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your words can be case insensitive you can leverage the insensitive flag `(?i)`

You can use a regex like this:

```
(?i)foo [a-z]*ing
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP0rY4/1)**

Btw, if multiple spaces can exist between `foo` and the next word you can use:

```
(?i)foo\s+[a-z]*ing
```

And if you consider that `ing` is not a word, then you can improve above to:

```
(?i)foo\s+[a-z]+ing
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you want `grep` to support Perl regex you can use:

```
grep -P '(?i)foo\s+[a-z]+ing'
```

Comment: the `\s` variants do not work for me in grep. the first one does.

Comment: @beta alright, then you can use `(?i)foo +[a-z]*ing` for multiple spaces

Comment: @beta if you want to use perl regex you have to use -P modifier `grep -P '(?i)foo\s+[a-z]+ing'`

Answer (score 2):

If you use .* will match everything, this will only match text:

```
"foo\s[a-zA-Z]+ing"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep -i "\bfoo [a-z]+ing\b"`
It uses word boundaries to ensure, that the word is just `foo`, but not `kafoo` and the following word is actually ending with ing, like `finding` but not `binged`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this grep command to match a word `foo` and next word ending with `ing`:

```
grep -Ew 'foo[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+ing' file
```

**Testing:**

```
cat <<'EOF' | grep -Ew 'foo[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+ing'
pqr foo going
bar foo walking
bar tofoo walking
foo running
abc def foo asdf asdfing
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
pqr foo going
bar foo walking
foo running
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with this short script using egrep instead of grep:

```
egrep -i "foo\s+\w+ing\b" foo.txt
```

which is directly equivalent to this:

```
grep -Ei "foo\s+\w+ing\b" foo.txt
```

The input file (poetry, really) that I came up with looks like this:

```
I was a little under the weather,
so I decided to foo going, and that involved
a lot of foo walking, and maybe just a little
bit of foo running, but certainly no foo
dancing or anything like that, because nobody wants
to be caught dancing any kind of way, especially
the foo way!
```

The output is as follows:

```
so I decided to foo going, and that involved
a lot of foo walking, and maybe just a little
bit of foo running, but certainly no foo
```

This was what I expected to see based on my reading of the description.